# Issues with Pandas Profiling

Tags: pandas, data-science, pandas-profiling

When I am trying to generate report using pandas profiling , I am getting below error while using below code:

KeyError: 'script_values'

```
import pandas_profiling
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
report = ProfileReport(df)
report
```

Can you please let me know why I am getting 'script_values' error. I googled all around but not able to find a solution.

Comment: EDIT: This has to do with new features in visions 0.4.2 (which are coupled to pandas-profiling v2.7.1). pip install "visions==0.4.1" should be a quick fix. I am getting the same error. I found one other post on stackoverflow from today so maybe it is an issue with a recent update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a compatibility issue with one of the dependencies. A fix has been released. Your problem should be resolved by updating to v2.7.1 (e.g. `pip install -U pandas-profiling`).

The manual steps as described by @jrp also work.